# Using a case statement while creating a list

Tags: c#, .net

I have a list which is a bunch of functions as displayed below

```
var listOfSteps = new List<StepList>
{
  new Setup(parameters),
  new InitializeClass(parameters),
  new calculate(parameters),
  //72 steps in total
}
```

I have to add another function to the list based on a condition.

int result = select something from someTable

```
var listOfSteps = new List<StepList>
{
  new Setup(parameters),
  new InitializeClass(parameters),
  new calculate(parameters),
  if (result = 5) {new display(parameters)},   //This is the additional step to be added
  //72 steps in total
}
```

I am trying to avoid creating 2 different sets for a simple if condition like below

```
if(result = 5)
{
  var listOfSteps = new List<StepList>  //list with the new function
  {
    new Setup(parameters),
    new InitializeClass(parameters),
    new calculate(parameters),
    new display(parameters),
    //72 steps in total
  }
}
else
{   //list without the new function
    new Setup(parameters),
    new InitializeClass(parameters),
    new calculate(parameters),
    //72 steps in total
}
```

Is there a way to implement this condition within the list creation?

Comment: Why don't you just put the if inside display(), or another function that calls display?

Comment: Not within the initializer, but what's stopping you from adding the condition after the initiaizer?

Comment: `var listOfSteps = new List<StepList> { ... }; if (result == 5) { listOfSteps.Add(...); }` -> I don't see the problem or complexity in that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Collection initializers are just syntactic sugar. Example:

```cs
var ints = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3 };

// is equivalent to

var temp = new List<int>();
temp.Add(1);
temp.Add(2);
temp.Add(3);
var ints = temp;
```

This means that you can simply add this new item conditionally afterwards:

```cs
var listOfSteps = new List<StepList>
{
  new Setup(parameters),
  new InitializeClass(parameters),
  new calculate(parameters),
  ...
}
if (result == 5) {
    listOfSteps.Add(new display(parameters));
}
```

Comment: Yes, this is what I implemented because none of the other solutions works for me.

But I couldn't call the listOfSteps.Add() after initialization because the order of the function was really important. So instead I just added it to the list during initialization and removed the step based on condition after initialization.

var displayObj = new display(parameters);

var listOfSteps = new List<StepList>
{
   new Setup(parameters),
   new InitializeClass(parameters),
   displayObj,
//all other functions
}

if (result != 5)
{
   listOfSteps.Remove(displayObj);
}

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be very readable if you can add a new kind of step - "do nothing":

```
// shouldn't StepList be renamed to "Step"?
class DoNothing: StepList {
    ...

    // implement this so that when the list of steps is processed,
    // this will do nothing
}
```

Then, you can use a simple ternary operator:

```
var listOfSteps = new List<StepList>
{
  new Setup(parameters),
  new InitializeClass(parameters),
  new calculate(parameters),
  result == 5 ? 
      new display(parameters)
      : 
      new DoNothing(),
}
```

It would be even more readable if you can make factory methods for all your steps, so that you don't have the word `new` all the time.

You can also use a switch expression:

```
var listOfSteps = new List<StepList>
{
  new Setup(parameters),
  new InitializeClass(parameters),
  new calculate(parameters),
  result switch { 
      5 => new display(parameters),
      _ => new DoNothing(),
  }
}
```

which would be very useful if you have more complicated decisions to make.

If the number of steps in the list of steps is important, you can always just remove the `DoNothing` steps from the list with a `Where` when you check the count.

```
listOfSteps.Where(step => step is not DoNothing).Count()
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me because the list is coupled with the UI and would display DoNothing() as one of the step which I'm trying to avoid as well.

Comment: @Jagath As I said at the end, the `DoNothing` steps can be very easily removed. Or your UI could be coded to explicitly not display them (in which case `Empty` might be a better name).

Comment: yes, deleting the DoNothing() function after initialize works.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that `StepList` is a class which causes some operation to be performed when its object is encountered. The problem you are facing is that, depending on external condition, one `StepList` object should be added or not, and that complicates `List` initialization, right?

If that is the issue, then you may introduce a special "do nothing" `StepList` subclass, e.g. called `Empty`. Your list initialization would then look like this:

```
var listOfSteps = new List<StepList>
{
    new Setup(parameters),
    new InitializeClass(parameters),
    new calculate(parameters),
    (result == 5 ? new display(parameters) : new Empty())
    // ... 72 steps in total
}
```

With this design, your list will always have the same number of items, but the result of their execution would depend on external condition.

Comment: This makes sense. So when the result is 5, I would assume that my variable listOfSteps would include display(parameters) as one of the value. But when it is not true, would Empty() be added as one of the value (even though it does nothing)

Comment: @Jagath That's the idea. This object would do nothing and have no UI representation.

Comment: I am getting an error "Empty is inaccessible due to its protection level" even though I haven't defined it. Is it private by default? Should I makes any changes before calling it in my function?

Answer (score 0):

I would use a method with `IEnumerable` as return type and do `yield return`s where necessary.

eg.

```
private IEnumerable<StepList> GetSteps()
{
   yield return new Setup(parameters);
   yield return new InitializeClass(parameters);
   yield return new calculate(parameters);
   if (result = 5) yield return new display(parameters);
   ...
}
```

and than intialize the list like this:

```
var listOfSteps = GetSteps().ToList();
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/yield